# How can I detect when a row is selected and non of rows is selected at jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a disabled button at my page. When a row selected at my grid I want to enable it. If any of rows is not selected it should be return to disable too. ,

How can I detect when a row is selected and non of rows is selected at jqgrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `multiselect: true` option you should do the following

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
    var selRows = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
    if (selRows.length === 0) {
        alert ("no rows are selected now");
        // you can disable the button
    } else {
        alert ("a row is selected now");
        // you can disable the button
    }
}
```

additionally you should include in the `loadComplete` the code which disable of the button because at the beginning, after changing the sort order or after filtering (if you use it) the rows will be not selected.